# Why when hide a div it's space exist there

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide a `div` when clicking a button. `div` hides well when clicking the button. But when div hides space still exists there.

It means there are two `div`(It can be more than two). I want to hide the div and space also and below `div` replace with hiding one.

I have mentioned my tried in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c2pnv7o6/17/

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like the "space" is coming from those `<br>` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say your problem is that you use those three `<br>` Tags. Those are not part of the div you are hiding. By hiding the ancor changes.

```
 <br><br><br>
```

Try putting them in the div you hide, or use margin properties.

Comment: ^ this. And also, try not to use <br> tags and definitely get rid of floats, try using something like flexbox or grid

Answer (score 1):

You are not removing the line breaks. Add them in the div element

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div id="prodcuctdiv">
    <h6 style="margin: 5px;" class="modal-title">New Products</h6>
    <div>
      <p style="border:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:green; padding: 0.5em; width: 15%; text-align: center; margin: 5px; float:left;">sss</p>
      <p style="border:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:green; padding: 0.5em; width: 15%; text-align: center; margin: 5px; float:left;">jjj</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onclick="myFunction1()" style="float:right;" id="addBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">Click me1</button>
    </div>
    <br><br><br> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first div is hidden when the button is clicked. The reason the second div does not move all the way to the top is because you have three `<br />` tags in the way. Remove them. Alternatively use `margin-bottom` on the `div` elements to provide the spacing, then when one is removed the white space is removed too.

In addition you should not use inline CSS or JS. Move that logic in to external stylesheet and script files. You should also look to amend the JS logic to use unobtrusive event handlers.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.test-btn').on('click', e => $(e.target).closest('.parent').hide());
});
```

```css
h6.modal-title {
  margin: 5px;
}

p {
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  float: right;
}

#prodcuctdiv,
#prodcuctCon {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div id="prodcuctdiv" class="parent">
    <h6 class="modal-title">New Products</h6>
    <div>
      <p>sss</p>
      <p>jjj</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="test-btn btn btn-secondary btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">Click me1</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="prodcuctCon" class="parent">
    <h6 class="modal-title">New Con</h6>
    <div>
      <p>mmm</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="test-btn btn btn-secondary btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">Click me2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```